# ProxyPass and ReverseProxy not working from outside the network

Tags: apache-http-server

I've been struggling with ProxyPass for a couple of weeks now.

My problem is that the result of any link that I expect to come from Server2 is the index.php page on Server1 when accessed from outside my network either from work via a VMware Client or via my mobile phone yet it all works as expected from inside my network.

I'm also planning to access my ZoneMinder installation on Server2 but I will wait until I have sorted the external access issue first thought it seems to work OK internally.

The following is the set up and I would really appreciate some help in getting it all going properly.

SteveW - Wellington - New Zealand

**Servers**

Server1 Raspberrypi2 running Raspbian (Debian Jessie)
    uname -a = Linux RASPBERRYPI 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

Server2 Lenovo M91p running Ubuntu desktop 14.04 LTS
    uname -a = Linux subdomain.domain.nz 3.19.0-47-generic #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 16:09:14 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Hosts files**

Server1 on 192.168.20.200

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi

192.168.20.200  domain.nz
192.168.20.210  subdomain.domain.nz
```

Server2 on 192.168.20.210

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       domain.nz

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.20.200 domain.nz
192.168.20.210 subdomain.domain.nz
```

**DNS Zone Records** (External providor)

```
domain.nz           A       my_ip_address
www.domain.nz       CNAME   domain.nz
subdomain.domain.nz CNAME   domain.nz
```

**Router port forwarding**

192.168.20.200 port 80 enabled 
192.168.20.200 port 443 enabled

SSL Certificates by letsencrypt

**Apache2 .conf files**

**Server1**

/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.nz file as follows:-

```
#domain.nz
#Redirect all incoming requests on 192.168.20.200 port 80 to port 443
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName domain.nz
    ServerAlias www.domain.nz
    Redirect permanent / https://domain.nz/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

#Port 443 on 192.68.20.200
<VirtualHost domain.nz:443>

    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName domain.nz
    #Web pages live below this
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.nz/public_html/

#Deny access to /
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#Allow Access to web pages
<Directory /var/www/domain.nz/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
    #Letsencrypt certificates
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nz/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nz/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nz/fullchain.pem

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

#subdomain.domain.nz
<VirtualHost subdomain.domain.nz:80>

    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName subdomain.domain.nz
    Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.domain.nz/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost subdomain.domain.nz:443>

    ServerName subdomain.domain.nz
    ProxyHTMLStripComments on
    ProxyRequests off
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLDoctype HTML

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Proxy *>
 Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / https://subdomain.domain.nz/
ProxyPassReverse / https://subdomain.domain.nz/
ProxyHTMLURLMap https://subdomain.domain.nz /

<Location />
  Require all granted
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Server2 on 192.168.20.210**

Lamp stack installed with website in /var/www/domain.nz/public_html/

/etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.domain.nz file as follows:-

```
#subdomain.domain.nz
#Redirect all incoming requests on 192.168.20.210 port 80 to port 443
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName subdomain.domain.nz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.domain.nz/public_html/
    Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.domain.nz/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

#Port 443 on 192.68.20.210
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName subdomain.domain.nz
    #Web pages live below this
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.domain.nz/public_html/
#Deny access to /
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
#Allow Access to web pages
<Directory /var/www/subdomain.domain.nz/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
    #Letsencrypt certificates
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.nz/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.nz/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.nz/fullchain.pem

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with this - anyone got any ideas????